# Implementing COUNT() and ROUND() method in LINQ query

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-web-api

For another example to get return data of a pivot table I'm defined a `LINQ` query to solve this problem. Well, now my question is how to count the values of a column?

Here the following C# Code:

```
var query = from q in db.DS
            where q.datum >= fromDate && q.datum <= toDate
            group q by q.quot_rate
              into grp
              select new
              {
                 Grade = grp.Key,
                 Total = grp.Select(t => new { t.fon, t.quot_rate }).AsQueryable()
              };

            var rate = (from q in db.DS
                        select q.fon).Distinct();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            dt.Columns.Add("Grade");

            foreach (var r in rate)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(r.ToString());
            }

            foreach (var q in query)
            {
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr["Grade"] = q.grade; //round q_grade

                foreach (var t in q.Total)
                {
                    dr[t.fon] = t.quot_rate; //count t.quot_rate
                }

                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }

            return dt;
```

You can see the comments where the numbers have to `ROUND()` and `COUNT()`.

How can I define this?

---

EDIT:

The output is currently as follows:

```
Grade | AB001 | AB002 | AB003 ...
90,045| 90,045| null  |  null
85,590| null  | 85,590|  85,590
85,450| null  | 85,450|  null
84,901| null  | 84,901|  null
```

and I want the result as follows:

```
Grade | AB001 | AB002 | AB003 ...
90    |   1   |   0   |    0
86    |   0   |   1   |    1
85    |   0   |   2   |    0
```

Comment: You are grouping by `quot_rate` but you name the property `Grade`, is that a typo? You need to explain your requirement better. Currently it's not clear what you're doing and what you actually want.

Comment: What do you want to count? Number of items in group, or number of different values in "quot_rate" column for each group?

Comment: @Andrei for example `quot_rate` = 90,509 , `AB001` = 90,509 is the view currently. And I want to `ROUND()` `quot_rate` values as 90,509 = 91 and `COUNT()` `AB001` = 1

Comment: @TimSchmelter `Grade` is called the columntitle and the `quot_rate` values added to the column `Grade`

Comment: @Andrei I'm updating my post.. see the output tables above.

Comment: @yuro, so to begin with you want round and only then group. Otherwise `84,901` and `85,450` will be different keys

Comment: @Andrei `84,901` and `85,450` have to be the same keys.

Comment: @yuro, that's exactly what I am taking about. You intended to do rounding after the query and the grouping, and I suggest rounding to happen before

Comment: @Andrei How can I handle this?

Comment: *For another example ...* You seem to think that we instantly know what you're talking about. Maybe it's a disappointment for you, but sometimes there are others who post questions. Make your questions stand-alone.

Answer (score 0):

So it appears that you actually want rounding to happen inside the query, so that you can do grouping by rounded values. So first part of the question can be answered as:

```
Grade = Math.Round(grp.Key),
```

Then the counts come out naturally as:

```
q.Total.Count()
```

However it seems that you actually want counts by `rate` items, so I would suggest something like that for each table row:

```
foreach (var r in rate)
{
    dr[r] = q.Total.Count(x => x.fon == r);
}
```